# Fileupload and ffmpeg processing in one step

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, ffmpeg

This is how I handle a file upload in my nodeJS / nestJS application. The file gets directly stored in mongodb using GridFSBucket.

```
const upload = async (file): Promise<any> => {
    const res = await new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        const { filename, mimetype, createReadStream } = await file

        // Write image to db
        const bucket = new GridFSBucket(this.db)
        const stream = createReadStream()
        const writeStream = bucket.openUploadStream(filename, { contentType: mimetype })
        writeStream.on('finish', async (file) => {
            // do some stuff
            resolve()
        })
        writeStream.on('error', (error) => {
            console.error(error)
            reject(error)
        })
        stream.on('error', (error) => writeStream.destroy(error))
        stream.pipe(writeStream)
    })
    return res
}
```

While this is working, I need to convert video files. Therefore I would like to use `ffmpeg`.

Something like (did not test this)

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ffmpeg()
    .input(downloadStream)
    .inputFormat("mp4")
    .setFfprobePath(pathToFfprobe.path)
    .setFfmpegPath(pathToFfmpeg)
    .videoCodec("libx264")
    .audioCodec("libmp3lame")
    .on("error", (err) => {
        console.error(err);
    })
    .save("./??.mp4"); // -> to DB
});
```

Is it possible to do the upload, processing and db storage in one workflow? In my code I do the upload and db storing in one step, but I do not get it how to handle the video file processing...